# Complete Line vector with end points in point shape

Tags: qgis, vector-layer

I have 2 different shapes:

- lines representing ducts
- points representing manholes/poles

Goal:

Fill in 2 different columns start_point and end_point of each line/duct where it touched the points shape.

Each points element has an ID that should be inserted in lines shape, identifying where the duct starts and ends.

Can you point me to the correct direction?

Comment: How do we consider a point touching line is starting or ending point?

Comment: I depends on my shapes quality. I've been testing around with intersects and join by location. The start and end point of a line should be used to draw it. The ducts /infra shape does not have the fields for start and end points created. I have a set of real examples. https://we.tl/t-6DWYpcC90V

Comment: You can upload to [wtrasfer](https://wetransfer.com) (for example) and share the link here.

Comment: [link]  we.tl/t-6DWYpcC90V

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an easy way of doing it with QGIS, but in Python with Geopandas would be something along the lines of:

For each line, search for the two closest points (either computing distance to each point if it's a small dataset, or using an rtree if it's big) and add the attribute of those two points to the line attributes.